# Spotify: failed to load application api-tutorial

Tags: spotify

I've searched everywhere but I couldn't find this question with an answer that helped with my problem.
I'm trying to make my first spotify app, but i can't get the first step to work.
I've downloaded the api tutorial (https://github.com/spotify/apps-tutorial), made a Spotify folder in My documents, enabled my developer account but still if I want to try the app by going to spotify:app:api-tutorial, I get the message: Failed to load application api-tutorial.

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you're on the [1.0 branch](https://github.com/spotify/apps-tutorial/tree/1.0) of the apps-tutorial project, the bundle identifier is actually 'tutorial', so you should type 'spotify:app:tutorial' into the search field.
- If you haven't, restart the Spotify client after you've moved or cloned the apps-tutorial project into the Spotify folder. Double check that it's in the [correct folder](http://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/guidelines/developer/#creatinganapp).

**Update:** The 1.0 branch has been removed, and its contents has been placed on the master branch. The 0.x versions of the API is now placed in the 0.x branch.